# Using Spring Solr Data or Not for Flexible Requests as Like Backup?

Tags: java, spring, solr, solrj, spring-data-solr

I want to implement an application at Spring that interacts with my current Solr or SolrCloud. I consider of using Spring Data Solr or not. However I think that there is no CloudSolrServer implemented at it yet on the other hand if I just run a query like that:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/replication?command=backup
```

and check whether backup is completed or not(I will do a get request, parse JSON and will see that last backup time is changed or not) How I can integrate it with Spring Data Solr?

I mean is it more meaningful using Spring + Solrj instead of Spring Data Solr at my situation (that is I want to do more flexible things that just CRUD operations on Solr with Spring)?

Answer (score 0):

True, there is no support for CloudSolrServer yet. What you can do is provide you own SolrServerFactory.

```java
public class CloudSolrServerFactory implements SolrServerFactory {

  private final CloudSolrServer solrServer;

  public CloudSolrServerFactory(String zkHost) throws MalformedURLException{
    this.solrServer = new CloudSolrServer(zkHost);
  }

  @Override
  public SolrServer getSolrServer() {
    return this.solrServer;
  }

  @Override
  public String getCore() {
    return "";
  }
}
```

Next you can add custom behavior to all your repositories as described in [Section 1.3 of Spring Data Commons](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html) documentation. Have a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/christophstrobl/5660566) (not an implementation of your issue, rather general usage of custom repositories) to get the idea of how it might work.

Please feel free to open a feature request as this is definitely something missing Spring Data Solr.

Comment: SolrServerFactory uses solrj 4.1.0 How can I change it to a newer version?

Comment: @kamaci using maven just exclude `solrj` from `spring-data-solr` and add dependency to desired version