# Solrcloud Backup & Restore indexed data

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

From last couple of weeks I am using `SolrCloud` on 3 development server with a single Load Balancer (in future I will extend it to 5 different server for Zookeeper and Solr). My current `SolrCloud` structure is like below.

```
Server 1 :  Java + Solr(port 8983) + Zookeeper(port 2181) 
Server 2 :  Java + Solr(port 8983) + Zookeeper(port 2181)
Server 3 :  Java + Solr(port 8983) + Zookeeper(port 2181)
```

Here I am able to create SOLR configuration from any server by uploading `conf` of my collection & **RELOAD** the collection using `COLLECITON API`, all my SOLR configuration is **syncing** and I am able to index and search my document perfectly. My collection had **1 shard** and **3 replica**, then I split the single shard to two. So basically its a single collection with **3 shard** and **3 replica** now.

So, now I have some questions

**Q1)** Is my current structure is **OK** ? or I need to change my current structure ?

**Q2)** How can I Backup and Restore my indexed collection data ?

**Q3)** What would happen if one of my server closed connection and then I am trying to backup and restore my solr data?

As I have seen the `COLLECTION API` endpoint to Backup and Restore collection data here at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-Backup

but couldn't figure out how to set the `path/to/my/shard/drive` and all that things on those two API endpoint to backup and restore my indexed data. Need help badly

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problem Solr collection api provides backup of complete collection from solr v6.0
[Using Spring Solr Data or Not for Flexible Requests as Like Backup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824701/using-spring-solr-data-or-not-for-flexible-requests-as-like-backup/40693969?noredirect=1#comment68632995_40693969)
goto above link you can get backup in that way 
need call backup command on each shard

Answer (score 0):

use location param to set path/to/my/shard/drive.
This path should be present on all your servers 1,2,3.
When running restore API, you need to provide the same Path.
restore will recover each shard using data present on path/to/my/shard/drive.

If you dont want to Backup on local filesystem, you can use hdfs as backup filesystem.
This can be done by adding a new repository in solr.xml. And using this repository name in Backup/Recovery API.

location and repository options are mutually exclusive.